# Web service to parse English sentences in real-time

Tags: web-services, node.js, nlp, language

Are there English language parsers that I can access via web-services, which can return the format of the sentence in real-time? I have looked at the Stanford parser, but wonder what the community recommends. It would also be good to understand the effectiveness of today's parsers.

Also, I would prefer access via web-services rather than local platform.

I currently use Node.js on Linux.

## Context

I have a 19yo autistic son (Aspergers), and I want to write a program to help him and others on the spectrum.

What I want is to receive their English sentences, have a web-service parse these sentences, and then formulate a response. That's really all.

Comment: What do you mean with "the format of the sentence"?

Comment: @unor It seems like the majority of parsers break up the sentence into constituents, so this is fine. I want to essentially create a conversation.

Comment: So, a hosted QA engine? Several answers per question? Anyone can see the QA, answer, post their own questions? Any registration needed?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul. No, I just need the sentence parsing. Ideally, I would like to send the sentence to some hosted platform which would return the sentence structure based on the constituents (like the Stanford parser works). I will take that sentence structure and (hopefully) return a meaningful response.

Comment: So you will be calling the web service from Node.js right?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul. Correct.

Comment: What do you think of the Stanford parser? Anything that could be improved? What would make a parser more adapted to your use case?